# E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] function_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: Node

Tags: python, tensorflow

Please help!
I have been running for a while now a model in Tensorflow 2.0, the model runs perfectly, but I think I'm missing efficiency because of this error, can someone please help me understand what is happening?

Thank you

Mi configuration:

Ubuntu LTS 18.04
 Inter Core i5
 32Gbs Ram
 2x NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB
 Running Python 3.7 Mirrored Strategy in both GPUs

The Error Line:

```
**2020-04-17 00:32:51.172839: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] function_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: Node 'replica_1/sequential_1/lstm_2/StatefulPartitionedCall_replica_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_1_27': Connecting to invalid output 33 of source node replica_1/sequential_1/lstm_2/StatefulPartitionedCall which has 33 outputs.**
```

The Console Output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

Train on 1283 samples, validate on 275 samples

Epoch 1/650

INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce: 8 all-reduces with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1, agg_small_grads_max_bytes = 0 and agg_small_grads_max_group = 10

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce: 8 all-reduces with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1, agg_small_grads_max_bytes = 0 and agg_small_grads_max_group = 10

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).

2020-04-17 00:32:51.172839: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] function_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: Node 'replica_1/sequential_1/lstm_2/StatefulPartitionedCall_replica_1/StatefulPartitionedCall_1_27': Connecting to invalid output 33 of source node replica_1/sequential_1/lstm_2/StatefulPartitionedCall which has 33 outputs.

2020-04-17 00:32:51.502923: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] 
Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10

2020-04-17 00:32:52.292452: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7

1283/1283 [==============================] - 11s 9ms/sample - loss: 0.0207 - accuracy: 0.0421 - val_loss: 0.0044 - val_accuracy: 0.0109
```

MyCode:

```
import ta
import math
import argparse
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error



def get_scaled_data(wdf, args):
    data = wdf.values[:-args.m_output]
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_X = scaler.fit_transform(data[:, :-args.m_output])
    scaled_y = y_scaler.fit_transform(data[:, -args.m_output:])
    scaled_data = np.concatenate((scaled_X,scaled_y), axis=1)
    return scaled_data, y_scaler

def get_X_y_split(data, args):
    data_size = len(data) - args.m_time_steps + 1
    series_X = []
    series_y = []
    for i in range(data_size):
        series_X.append(data[i:i + args.m_time_steps,:-args.m_output])
        series_y.append(data[i + args.m_time_steps - 1, -args.m_output:])
    series_X = np.array(series_X)
    series_y = np.array(series_y)
    train_X, X, train_y, y = train_test_split(series_X, series_y, test_size=0.3)
    valid_X, test_X, valid_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5)
    return train_X, test_X, valid_X, train_y, test_y, valid_y

def make_model(args):
    mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
    with mirrored_strategy.scope():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(args.m_neurons, input_shape=(args.m_time_steps, args.m_features), return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(args.m_dropout))
        model.add(LSTM(args.m_neurons, return_sequences=False))
        model.add(Dense(args.m_output))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=args.m_learning_rate, clipnorm=args.m_max_grad_norm), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Specify Params for Experimental Setting")

    parser.add_argument('--m_epochs', type=int, default=650)                        
    parser.add_argument('--m_batch_size', type=int, default=100) 
    parser.add_argument('--m_neurons', type=int, default=128)
    parser.add_argument('--m_dropout', type=float, default=0.0) 
    parser.add_argument('--m_learning_rate', type=float, default=1e-3)
    parser.add_argument('--m_max_grad_norm', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--m_time_steps', type=int, default=168)
    parser.add_argument('--m_features', type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument('--m_output', type=int, default=24)   
    return parser.parse_args()


#####################################################################
#####################################################################

def get_errors(model, test_X, test_y):
    pred_y = model.predict(test_X)    
    inv_pred_y = y_scaler.inverse_transform(pred_y)
    inv_test_y = y_scaler.inverse_transform(test_y)
    rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_test_y, inv_pred_y))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(inv_test_y, inv_pred_y)
    return rmse, mae


def get_model_run_test(args):
    model = make_model(args)
    model.fit(train_X,train_y, epochs=args.m_epochs,validation_data=(valid_X,valid_y),batch_size=args.m_batch_size,shuffle=True)
    rmse, mae = get_errors(model, test_X, test_y)
    print(f'epochs: {args.m_epochs} ==> RMSE: %.2f, MAE: %.2f' % (rmse, mae))      
    return model, rmse, mae


args = get_arguments()

databook = refresh_data()

for key in databook.keys():
    df = databook[key].copy()
    data, y_scaler = get_scaled_data(df,args) 
    train_X, test_X, valid_X, train_y, test_y, valid_y = get_X_y_split(data,args)
    args.m_features = train_X.shape[-1]

    model, rmse, mae = get_model_run_test(args)
```

Please help, i havent been able to find an answer and dont know whats going on. I Think it might be some model configuration, or something but im not entirely sure
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed in the latest version of Tensorflow. Please take a look at commit for the fix https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3a03164a24ea7dbfe221e84ca62e2a39b745c379